# If exist and errorlevels in a batch (.bat) file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I'm trying to run a delete command on the result of an SQL command but only if it returns an error code of 0. Below is my code:

```
SqlCmd command...

REM if SqlCmd command is successful run the below if exist statement
if errorlevel 0 (

REM if the file exists then delete and exit:
    if exist D:\Temp\database.bak(
        del "D:\Temp\database.bak"
        exit /B
    )
REM if the file doesn't exist, exit with error code 1:
    else(
            echo The file does not exist
            exit /B 1
    )

)
REM if SqlCmd is not successful, exit:
if errorlevel 1 exit /B %errorlevel%
```

Currently, I'm getting a syntax error but I can't see where I'm going wrong. Any help would be useful as I'm new to batch, thanks!

Comment: The parenthesis needs a space: "D:\Temp\database.bak (" and the else clause has to be on the same line as the parenthesis: ") else (".

Comment: `if errorlevel 0` means: "if errorlevel is greater or equal 0", that is, all the values! Use: `if not errorlevel 1`, that is: "if errorlevel is less than 1"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
REM if SqlCmd command is successful run the below if exist statement
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (

REM if the file exists then delete and exit:
    if exist "D:\Temp\database.bak" (
        del "D:\Temp\database.bak"
        exit /B
    ) else (
REM if the file doesn't exist, exit with error code 1:    
        echo The file does not exist
        exit /B 1
    )

)
REM if SqlCmd is not successful, exit:
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" exit /B %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Or maybe you could try with some GOTO statements :

```
REM if SqlCmd command is successful run the below if exist statement
if NOT "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" GOTO next

REM if the file exists then delete and exit:
    if exist "D:\Temp\database.bak" (
        del "D:\Temp\database.bak"
        exit /B
    ) else (
REM if the file doesn't exist, exit with error code 1:    
        echo The file does not exist
        exit /B 1
    )


:next
REM if SqlCmd is not successful, exit:
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" exit /B %ERRORLEVEL%
```